# Importing specific columns from excel to an existing sql database table

Tags: sql-server

I have an excel spreadsheet with columns A-O but i only need to import specific columns A, F and O into a sql database table with a different column header(1,3 and 5). I know that i have to a write T-Sql script. Please can someone help with the script?

Comment: I don't think t-sql will help you here.

Comment: If using SSMS you can right click on your database.  Choose Tasks then Import Data....  This will launch a wizard that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest you do

Hold down the control key and click on the three columns you want (these should now be selected).

Hit Control-C to copy.

Create a new spreadsheet and paste your three columns.

Select save as CSV file type.

This CSV can be imported to SQL using SQL Server tools -- look for importing CSV to SQL Server.

Comment: Great idea but how do i import them to the specific columns in the database. For example ( how do i make column A to be imported into column 1 ?)